# How can charm mesons conserve charge?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, standard-model, antimatter, mesons

If a charm meson can change from particle to antiparticle. Then how can charge be conserved if they have different charges. what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the neutral charm mesons (${ { D }^{ 0 } }$ and $\overline { { D }^{ 0 } }$)  can change from particle to antiparticle, and the neutral charm mesons have no charge.